# how to select distinct records in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I want to select distinct rows on some condition but when i am adding id column in select statement it returns all the rows???

the below query is working fine

```
select distinct dst_bnk_acnt_id
,dst_cust_id
,org_cust_id
,dst_pos_id
,pmt_typ_cd 
from tb_cm_t_pmt_coll
where org_pos_id = 8 OR dst_pos_id = 8 OR dst_bnk_acnt_id = 1 ;
```

but when i want to select a latest record using order by id(desc) it returns all rows!

```
SELECT  distinct id
,dst_bnk_acnt_id
,dst_cust_id
,org_cust_id
,dst_pos_id
,pmt_typ_cd  
FROM  tb_cm_t_pmt_coll
WHERE org_pos_id = 8 OR dst_pos_id = 8 OR dst_bnk_acnt_id = 1 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

i know 'id' column is primary key  and all its values are unique and because of this all rows becomes unique.

i want to select a distinct row using these **`[dst_bnk_acnt_id,dst_cust_id,org_cust_id,dst_pos_id,pmt_typ_cd]`** columns only but i also want to order them using id in descending order.

please help.

Comment: do you need id in the result?

Comment: if you want to just order the result by id you can do it without put id in select list.

Comment: no i dont want id in the result.

Comment: @krishnPatel can you tell me please that how to do it

Comment: You cannot have unique values that do not include the ID, and sort by the ID at the same time. I guess you have to find a column that is included in the unique columns list to sort by.

Comment: Show us example data - source and desired result.

Comment: @Rene That's the only problem here. But i want to order them using id column only , is there any way to di it?

Comment: Why? If the value is not in the result what's the point of sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use window functions for that:

```
select id,
       dst_bnk_acnt_id,
       dst_cust_id, 
       org_cust_id,
       dst_pos_id,
       pmt_typ_cd
FROM (
  SELECT id,
         dst_bnk_acnt_id,
         dst_cust_id, 
         org_cust_id,
         dst_pos_id,
         pmt_typ_cd, 
         row_number() over (partition by dst_bnk_acnt_id,dst_cust_id,org_cust_id,dst_pos_id,pmt_typ_cd 
                            order by id desc) as rn  
  FROM  tb_cm_t_pmt_coll
  WHERE org_pos_id = 8 
     OR dst_pos_id = 8 
     OR dst_bnk_acnt_id = 1 
)  
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

The `order by id desc` in the window function gives the row with the highest `id` the row number 1, picking the latest `id` for each combination of the distinct columns.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have your tables so I'll use Scott's sample schema.

Distinct departments and jobs are:

```
SQL> select distinct deptno, job from emp;

    DEPTNO JOB
---------- ---------
        20 CLERK
        30 SALESMAN
        20 MANAGER
        30 CLERK
        10 PRESIDENT
        30 MANAGER
        10 CLERK
        10 MANAGER
        20 ANALYST

9 rows selected.
```

We'd want to sort data per `EMPNO` (which is something like your `ID`):

```
SQL> select distinct deptno, job from emp order by empno;
select distinct deptno, job from emp order by empno
                                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression


SQL>
```

It won't work (as you already know). But, if you use a subquery (or a CTE), then you get this:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select min(empno) id, deptno, job
  3     from emp
  4     group by deptno, job
  5     order by 1 desc
  6    )
  7  select deptno, job
  8  From temp
  9  order by id desc;

    DEPTNO JOB
---------- ---------
        10 CLERK
        30 CLERK
        10 PRESIDENT
        20 ANALYST
        10 MANAGER
        30 MANAGER
        20 MANAGER
        30 SALESMAN
        20 CLERK

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

which means that your query might look like this:

```
WITH temp
     AS (  SELECT MIN (id) id,
                  dst_bnk_acnt_id,
                  dst_cust_id,
                  org_cust_id,
                  dst_pos_id,
                  pmt_typ_cd
             FROM tb_cm_t_pmt_coll
            WHERE    org_pos_id = 8
                  OR dst_pos_id = 8
                  OR dst_bnk_acnt_id = 1
         GROUP BY dst_bnk_acnt_id,
                  dst_cust_id,
                  org_cust_id,
                  dst_pos_id,
                  pmt_typ_cd)
  SELECT dst_bnk_acnt_id,
         dst_cust_id,
         org_cust_id,
         dst_pos_id,
         pmt_typ_cd
    FROM temp
ORDER BY id DESC;
```